# Python package not working as expected on docker image

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, pip, airflow

So I have created a python package for my scripts to install on `airflow docker` image.
The python package works as expected on my local machine:

[image]

But when I add the same package to `airflow docker` in `Dockerfile` the package gets installed, but I am unable to import it same as it works on my local machine.
[image]

If I do something like this:

```
import reddit_etl_abd as etl
```

This doesnt give any error on airflow.